# How to use findAndModify with a Node.js MongoDB driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What is wrong with the code below?

```
db.get().collection('bars').findAndModify({
    barID: req.body.button
},{
    $push: {
        usersfbID: req.body.profileUser[0].facebookID,
        usersDocID: req.body.profileUser[0]._id
    }
},{
    new: true
}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }if(doc){
        console.log('Existing document updated successfully');
        console.log(doc);
    }
});
```

I always get the same error,

> MongoError: exception: nextSafe(): { $err: "Can't canonicalize query:
>   BadValue bad sort specification", code: 17287 }

What am I doing wrong? Am I misusing the $push operator? Do I need to provide quotes around some of the key value pairs? This findAndModify method is driving me crazy. I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong.

Note: I have been through the other questions on SO regarding findAndModify, but none of those solutions is working for me. I'm sure its a small error regarding the syntax for the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`findAndModify`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findAndModify)** method has the following signature

```
findAndModify(query, sort, doc, options, callback)
```

where

- **`query`** `<object>` : The query object to locate the object to modify.
- **`sort`** `<array>` : If multiple docs match, choose the first one in the specified sort order as the object to manipulate.
- **`doc`** `<object>` : The fields/vals to be updated.
- **`options`** `<object>` optional: Optional settings.

The reason why you are getting the error is because the **`sort`** specification is missing and instead it's reading the update **`doc`** as the **`sort`** parameter.

You need to specify the sort parameter as follows:

```
db.get().collection('bars').findAndModify(
    { "barID": req.body.button },   // query
    [ ["barID", 1] ],               // sort
    {
        "$push": {                   // doc
            "usersfbID": req.body.profileUser[0].facebookID,
            "usersDocID": req.body.profileUser[0]._id
        }
    },
    { "new": true },                // options
    function(err, doc){             // callback
        if (err){
            throw err;
        } else if(doc){
            console.log('Existing document updated successfully');
            console.log(doc);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thanks a lot! You were right, I was just missing the sort parameter. I thought that was an optional parameter, but apparently not. Also, can I insert a new document using findAndModify by setting upsert: true?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun Yes, if the `upsert` option is set to true, mongo creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.