# How to indicate an update with findAndModify method in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on an app using MongoDB and Express.js.

I am creating a post handler that updates a toy (found by its id) with a new proposed name for the toy (which is pushed onto a nameIds array that contains the ids of the other proposed names):

```
router.post('/names', (req, res) => {
  const toyId = req.body.toyId;
  const name = req.body.newName;

  mdb.collection('names').insertOne({ name }).then(result =>
   mdb.collection('toys').findAndModify({
     query: { id: toyId },
     update: { $push: { nameIds: result.insertedId } },
     new: true
   }).then(doc =>
     res.send({
       updatedToy: doc.value,
       newName: { id: result.insertedId, name }
     })
   )
  )
});
```

However, when I test this, I receive this error:

```
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'Either an update or remove=true must be specified',
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'Either an update or remove=true must be specified',
code: 9,
codeName: 'FailedToParse'
```

I'm not new to MongoDB, but this simple call is baffling me.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325687/nodejs-and-mongodb-findandmodify-need-remove-or-update & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029068/how-to-use-findandmodify-with-a-node-js-mongodb-driver & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648610/mongodb-findandmodify-node-js. Looks like you are missing required arguments.

Comment: This is nodejs mongodb not mongo shell. So use node mongo commands and also add nodejs tag in your post

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That is the format for mongo shell. Using mongo driver you would call with these arguments:

```
.findAndModify( //query, sort, doc, options, callback
  { id: toyId }, //query
  [], //sort
  { $push: { nameIds: result.insertedId } }, // doc update
  { new: true }, // options
  function(err,result){ //callback
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } else {
      res.send({
        updatedToy: result.value,
        newName: { id: result.insertedId, name }
      })    
    }
  }
)
```